# What is required to build up a basic sqlite database server on my laptop

Tags: php, android, sqlite

Thank you for the time reading this.

I am planning on creating an Android app that is communicating with my own SQLite database server\webpage that is located on my private laptop.
I have no previous knowledge/experience with PHP nor hosting a webpage in this case.
My question is what is required to make the most basic online database server so I could easily and very basically request and fetch SQLite queries within the Android app from the database that is on my laptop.
Are there any programs I have to own?
Also my first intentions is for it to work on my local network(My Wifi at home), and then make it global.

Any help is appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: [SQLite Is Serverless](http://www.sqlite.org/serverless.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do isn't possible. SQLite is used only as a local storage i.e. a file on the local PC that is being read from. In order to do what you want to do you would need to install a database server on your laptop. MySQL is probably best as this is free for personal use.

Comment: will it allow me to fetch data using a php request from an app on a phone?

Comment: Yes, you would tell the app to post to your server, in your example, your laptop with whatever information is needed, then your PHP pages would access the database via localhost and return the data back to your app, it would need to json encode to the result set. then the android app decodes the json data to display whatever information is needed

Comment: Yes, this is what I wanted to end up with exactly. Thank you, will I need any other programs apart of MySQL Server?

Comment: Only, the android development tools. MySQL workbench might be useful for viewing, creating databases and tables, or PhpMyAdmin can be installed on a web server on your laptop, although I prefer workbench. Not required but a separate IDE for doing the PHP development I think is a good idea as well, NetBeans is a good PHP IDE.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest getting a VPS for like £6 a month and hosting a database on there. I use Chunkhost and they seem amazing for the price. There are many tutorials for setting up a MySql database on there and administering it.

I would also suggest making it a web application first before trying to integrate it with Android, that way you're learning one thing at a time and not 2 (php/mysql and then android integration).